# org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException: ids for this class must be manually assigned before calling save(): while id is autogenerate in oracle

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, oracle, hibernate

I am working on `spring 4.0` and `hibernate 4.0.1` project in eclipse and using oracle as database. If I make some changes in database then changes will not affect by eclipse. Eg. I generate id in oracle this code is successfully executed in eclipse. But after that I again make some changes in database same code is not running it gives me error as

```
org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException: ids for this class must be manually assigned before calling save():
```

Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: How do you increment id?

Comment: Incerement id by generating sequense in oracle

Comment: Please post your mapping

Comment: @Id
@Column(name="user_Id",length=12)
private String userId;

Comment: I will add as answer

Answer (score 1):

The meaning of your exception is **id have not setted correctly**.The error is in your mapping.If your are using `sequence` for incrementing id you must also do this in mapping.Try following:

```
@GeneratedValue(generator = "yourSequenceName", strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
private int id;
```

I hope this will help you.